# My unity project is Freezing with this script i don't know what have i done wrong

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My unity project is freezing and there are no errors before clicking play button after that it freezes the code:

In this code I am trying to detect if the player is triggering enemy collider with `OnTriggerStay2D`
so if it does I want the code to add score every second with `IEnumerator` function. But if the player is not colliding with the enemy for more than 2 seconds it gets destroyed.

The code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Trigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject other;
    bool touching = false;
    int score = 0;

    public void Update()
    {
        AddScore();
    }

    private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        Debug.Log("Touching");
        touching = true;
    }

    public void AddScore()
    {
        if(touching == true)
        {
            while (touching == true)
            {
                score++;
                StartCoroutine(wait());
            }
            Debug.Log(score);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Not Touching");
            StartCoroutine(waiter());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator waiter()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(2);
        Destroy(other);
    }

    IEnumerator wait()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you set `touching` back to `false`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete `while (touching == true)`, that is breaking your game.

The if condition should be enough for the logic.

Comment: Now i have done that correction the object is getting destroyed after starting the game in 2secs even it is showing touching with debug.log the object is getting destroyed even though it is triggering the object ??????

Comment: I'm not familiar with Coroutines, but it seems wrong. It might be stuff for antoher question